# Apache Spark 2.2.0 blockmanager memory calculation

Tags: apache-spark

If I launch a spark-submit with executor memory 1G and driver memory 1G in yarn mode.
I see the following things in the Spark logs:

> INFO org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.10.11.116:36011 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.10.11.116, 36011, None)
>   INFO org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager vm-souvik-1.novalocal:36075 with 414.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, vm-souvik-1.novalocal, 36075, None)

I have searched and found the following lines in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala prints the following info

```
logInfo("Registering block manager %s with %s RAM, %s".format(
    id.hostPort, Utils.bytesToString(maxOnHeapMemSize + maxOffHeapMemSize), id))
```

My questions are
1. from which property does Spark gets the `maxOnHeapMemSize` and `maxOffHeapMemSize` value?
2. Why is there a difference between the values shown for driver and executor even though both have been launched with same memory?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "memory management" section of the [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management) and in particular how the property `spark.memory.fraction` is applied to your memory configuration when determining how much on heap memory to allocation the Block Manager. To answer your question the values are derived from what you have already set for the Executor/Driver.

The property `spark.memory.offHeap.size` would only be considered if it was enabled.

You may be able to gleam more details from your logs if you increase your log level.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager=TRACE
```